# How to find "initial resolution time" for a case in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

How can I create a workflow (or other method) to show me the initial resolution time for a case? Looking at the "Modified Time" isn't good enough as that will update if a case reopens and is re-resolved.

I've created a field called "Initial Resolution" and then created a workflow to run when the case's status changes to **Resolved** BUT when it runs, it errors saying "This case has already been resolved. Close and reopen the case record to see the updates"

I'm assuming that this means you can't run a workflow against a closed case, but how can I get the initial resolution time off the back of it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a CRM 2013 or later instance, you should be able to create a **real-time workflow** that runs before the action and updates a field that represents the initial resolution date.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is the way I went - one drawback is that you can't differentiate between a case that is being resolved and a case that is being cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following:

1. Create a field of date time field that will store initial resolution
   datetime.
2. Develop a plugin that will handle Resolve message for a case and
   populate field created in point 1 with current datetime.
3. Use that field.

Comment: So no way via customisation, just extension? :(

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the customizations only, you will have to store the date time in an entity that, has the record still active after the case is resolved.

Like:

1. Create a field of date time that will store initial resolution datetime, on an existing related entity of the case, or you could create a custom entity of your own. My first idea was the Case Resolution entity, but this one is locked for new fields.
2. Make a workflow that will run on status change for the resolved statuses and populate that date time field.

If You are using CRM 2015 you could try doing it on the case with real-time workflows to set the value of the field on the case.

As per this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481598.aspx) you should be able to run a real-time workflow pre update of the case.

***Quote from there:***

*The real-time workflow can execute before (pre-operation), after (post-operation), or during the core operation. A real-time workflow that is executed during the core operation is the implementation of a custom action. Real-time workflows can be ranked within a stage just like you can do with plug-ins.*

Be aware that i have not tested this however, and i am not sure if it would be doable on CRM 2013 also.